# DolphinDB - add columns before streaming engine and after subscribing data

Tags: streaming, subscription, dolphindb

If I want to add columns while filtering, what should I do if the table structure changes?

```
share streamTable(1000:0, `time`a, [TIMESTAMP, DOUBLE]) as table
outputTable = table(10000:0, `time`a, [TIMESTAMP, DOUBLE, DOUBLE])
def append_after_filtering(mutable inputTable, msg){
t = select * from msg
insert into inputTable values(t.time,t.a)
}
Aggregator = createTimeSeriesEngine(name="Aggregator", windowSize=6, step=3, metrics=<[avg(a)]>, dummyTable=table, outputTable=outputTable, timeColumn=`time)
subscribeTable(tableName="table", actionName="test", offset=0, handler=append_after_filtering{Aggregator}, msgAsTable=true)
```

I want to add a column to calculate a+100 as column b in append_after_filtering.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another shared stream table (table2), and use handler to add columns on the data subscribed by subscribeTalbe (table1) in DolphinDB. The calculated table structure is table2, and set the dummyTable of createTimeSeriesEngine as table2.

```
share streamTable(1000:0, `time`a, [TIMESTAMP, DOUBLE]) as table1
share streamTable(1000:0, `time`a`b, [TIMESTAMP, DOUBLE, DOUBLE]) as table2
outputTable = table(10000:0, `interval_time`a`b, [TIMESTAMP, DOUBLE, DOUBLE])

def append_after_filtering(mutable inputTable, msg){
t = select * from msg
t[`b] = t.a+100
insert into inputTable values(t.time,t.a,t.b)
}
Aggregator = createTimeSeriesEngine(name="Aggregator", windowSize=6, step=3, metrics=<[avg(a), avg(b)]>, dummyTable=table2, outputTable=outputTable, timeColumn=`time)
subscribeTable(tableName="table1", actionName="test", offset=0, handler=append_after_filtering{Aggregator}, msgAsTable=true)
```